# RC circuit energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I am quite new at circuit analysis and I have a question about a RC circuit, with the resistor and the capacitor connected in series. I want to find the energy supplied by the ideal voltage source given that the capacitor is not charged, until it's fully charged. However, I am a bit lost because of the resistor, which I am sure that will also consume some energy.  Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: You solve the differential equations for voltage and current and then you calculate the integral of the power lost in the resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy balance can be considered by noting that the work done in moving a charge $\delta q$ across a potential difference $V$ is $V \delta q$ and an integration can be done to find the total amount of work done $\int V dq$ whilst moving a finite amount of charge.

This integration is equivalent to finding the area under a potential difference against charge graph.

[image]

Applying KVL to a series battery, resistor and capacitor circuit gives the relation between the emf of the battery $\mathcal E$, the potential difference across the resistor $v_R$ and the potential difference across the capacitor $v_C$

$\mathcal E - v_R - v_C = 0$

When the capacitor is fully charged $v_R = 0$ and $v_C = \mathcal E$.

The relationship between the potential difference $v_C$ across a capacitor of capacitance $C$  and the charge stored $q$ is $v = \frac 1 C q$

Assume that the capacitor is originally uncharged and that the final charge stored on it is $Q$ and then the potential difference across the capacitor is $\mathcal E$.
Graph 1 shows the variation of potential difference with charge stored.
The work done is the area under the graph and equal to the energy stored in the capacitor $\frac 1 2 \mathcal E Q$.

Since $v_R = \mathcal E - v_C$ graph 2 shows the variation of voltage across the resistor and the charge which has flowed through the resistor.
The area under this graph is the work done by the battery in driving charge through the resistor which is equal to the energy dissipated in the resistor as heat.
That again is $\frac 1 2 \mathcal E Q$.

In charging the capacitor the battery has driving a charge $Q$ around the circuit and has done work equal to $\mathcal E Q$ and this has come from a chemical reaction within the battery.
This is graph 3.

So using KVL which comes from the law of conservation of energy, the definition of potential difference and the defining equation for capacitance we have

Electrical energy supplied by the battery $(\mathcal C \mathcal E^2)$
= energy stored in the capacitor $(\frac 12 C \mathcal E^2)$ + energy dissipated as heat in the resistor $(\frac 12 C \mathcal E^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the RC circuit connected to a battery, the current through the circuit is given by a formula of the form (the switch is closed at $t= 0$) $I(t) = I_0 \, \exp(-t/\tau)$. At any instant the power dissipated by the resistor is given by $I^2(t) R$ and to determine the total energy dissipated by the resistor you have to integrate over time.

As well, the battery has to use energy to charge the capacitor: When the capacitor has an amount charge $Q(t)$ on its plates, it requires some energy by the battery to push an extra amount of charge onto the plates (since like charges repel).

The amount of energy provided by the battery to fully charge the capacitor is $\frac{1}{2} C V^2$, where $V$ is the final potential across the capacitor (which will be equal to the emf of the battery, since as $t \to \infty, I(t) \to 0$ so the pd across R is zero).